# SQL performance vs. redundancy

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

How should I design the following database?

I have a table, where each of the ~15000 userNames is connected to an average of 7 group names:

```
TABLE usergroups
userName VarChar, groupName VarChar
Alexander, Developers
Alexander, Software
Alexander, Company
Michael, Testers
Michael, Software
Michael, London
Michael, Company
```

I have another table, where I store ACL rules defined by the admin.

An ACL rule states that some users or groups are allowed to access data of other persons or groups in a certain way. From groups, users (e.g. the boss) may be excluded:

```
TABLE aclRules
ruleId, fromUsers, toUsers, fromExclude, toExclude, permissions
1, "Software,HR","Testers,HR","Michael,Michelle","William","RWX"
```

My guess is that more than 500 rules are not manageable, perhaps even less.

Given two userIds (1 -> 2) I want to fetch all ACL rules that allow userId 1 to access data of userId 2. Such queries will be done fairly often (I estimate ~15M times a day, but it could be even more), while changes to the rules/group memberships will not exceed 1000 a day.

I now see two possibilities how to design my database.

**First possibility:** I could design a helper table in the following way:

```
TABLE aclUsers
ruleId int,fromUser VarChar,toUser VarChar
1,"Alexander","Michael"
```

and populate it with all usernames that I calculate once from the group names entered in the rules table. So, in fact, *it stores redundant data*.

In the worst case, it would store 15000*15000 = 225M entries for *one* rule, but let's assume around 10M entries overall when used as we expect it to be used. *A problem is: when groups are changed, I will have to rebuild this table.*

But at least the ACL query would be easy - and hopefully also fast:

```
SELECT FROM aclRules WHERE ruleId IN
(SELECT ruleId FROM aclUsers WHERE fromUser = @userName1 AND toUser = @userName2)
```

(Which could be done easier with a join)

**Second possibility:** I could calculate the group memberships on the fly.

I would of course split fromUsers, toUser, fromExclude and toExclude from aclRules table into four different tables for easier access:

```
TABLE aclFromUser
ruleId int, fromUser VarChar
1, Software
1, HR

TABLE aclToUser
ruleId int, toUser VarChar
1, Testers
1, HR

TABLE aclFromExclude
ruleId int, fromExclude VarChar
1, Michael
1, Michelle

TABLE aclToExclude
ruleId int, toExclude VarChar
1, William
```

My guesstimate is that every of these tables will have around 1000 entries.

The query would then look like

```
SELECT FROM aclRules WHERE 
    ruleId IN(SELECT ruleId FROM aclFromUser WHERE fromUser IN(SELECT groupname FROM usergroups WHERE username = @userName1))
AND ruleId IN(SELECT ruleId FROM aclToUser WHERE toUser IN(SELECT groupname FROM usergroups WHERE username = @userName2))
AND ruleId NOT IN(SELECT ruleId FROM aclFromExempt WHERE fromExclude IN(SELECT groupname FROM usergroups WHERE username = @userName1))
AND ruleId NOT IN(SELECT ruleId FROM aclToExempt WHERE toExclude IN(SELECT groupname FROM usergroups WHERE username = @userName2))
```

(Which should run faster if I implement it as a stored procedure)

This spares me the problem of syncing changes of the usergroups table into the redundant aclUsers table, but how will it affect the execution time?

**Which design should I prefer, and why?**

**How much would be the time penalty of the second version?**

Comment: I would do nothing you described.  I would go with a normalized design.  If you don't know what that means, or think your design is normalized, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.  Regarding your comment about, everyone in the group except bosses, I would either go with two groups or a UserType field, depending on how everything was organized in your workplace.

Comment: So you would use my second approach, but use integer Ids instead of names everywhere to reach 3NF. Is this correct?

Comment: The groups are defined by the admin and will be used for other things as well, like messages sent to a whole group. The admin won't define that user x is the Boss and should as such be excluded from the acl, because there are indefinitely many reasons why one person may be excluded from an ACL - most boil down to whether the persons have to store confidential data in the system. There may be a rule that allows HR to look at all documents tagged "Vacation", except those which are put into the system by union spokespersons (because this group handles complaints when vacation was refused).

Comment: One person may be excluded from one acl, but not from the other, and for various reasons. I can't think of how to put this down in a UserType field.

Comment: No I would not use your 2nd approach with numeric keys.  I would do what I said I would do at the end of my original comment.